# Can I create derived collections of a derived type cleanly?

Tags: c#, inheritance, covariance

I have three classes:

- `Animal`
- `Giraffe : Animal`
- `Tiger : Animal`

... and want to implement three dictionary classes:

```
public abstract class AnimalDictionary
{
    internal Dictionary<int, Animal> _internalDictionary;

    //TODO: Dictionary interface implementation, minus the "Add" method
}

public class GiraffeDictionary : AnimalDictionary, IDictionary<int, Giraffe>
{
    //Collection Code Examples
    public List<Giraffe> GetGiraffesWithHerdID(int herdID);
    public void FleeFromTigers(TigerDictionary pride);
}

public class TigerDictionary : AnimalDictionary, IDictionary<int, Tiger>
{
    //Collection Code Examples
    public List<Tiger> GetActiveHunters();
    public void HuntGiraffeHerd(GiraffeDictionary targetHerd);
}
```

I'm well aware that the base `AnimalDictionary` cannot implement `IDictionary` or `ICollection` because of the problems being able to put a Tiger in a `GiraffeDictionary` would cause. I won't pretend to understand properly covariance and contravariance, but I do get why you can't put tigers in the giraffe pen.

Instead, I've implemented `AnimalDictionary` by having it inherit  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Animal>>`, and just made it implement all the same methods as a dictionary, minus `Add()`, since Add() will be implemented in the derived classes.

Unfortunately, implementing `IDictionary` in the derived collection classes has given me this bit of ugliness in GiraffeDictionary and TigerDictionary:

- `ICollection<Giraffe> IDictionary<int, Giraffe>.Values => _internalDictionary.Values.Cast<Giraffe>().ToList();`

This concerns me, since I expect to be iterating over these collections in tight loops. I want to be able to iterate over the Values collection without the performance cost of casting and creating a whole new list, but Values is an ICollection, not an IEnumerable.

How can I resolve this problem? Is there an alternative approach that I'm missing, or should I give up on having a base class entirely and just accept that I'll have duplicate methods in the derived collection classes?

Comment: how about a generic AnimalDictionary<T> class

Comment: I need a still place to implement unique methods in GiraffeDictionary and TigerDictionary. I will modify the examples given above to clarify.

Comment: You can implement your derived class specific implementation in derived classes for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the generic `AnimalDictionary<T>` will be helpful here and we can write the common method in the generic class which can be re-used by the other derived types. Here is a sample I composed which should give some idea how to approach this:

```
public class AnimalDictionary<T> where T : Animal
{
    
}
```

We can define the common generic method in the `AnimalDictionary<T>` type so that we don't have two duplicate the common behaviors in the other types of `Animal`

and inside the generic type we can have a generic dictionary field like:

```
IDictionary<int,T> animalDictionary;
```

Here are the related stubs:

```
public class Animal
{
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
}
```

and the calling code would be like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    AnimalDictionary<Cat> catDictionary = new AnimalDictionary<Cat>();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Now we can add behaviors like this:

```
public class AnimalDictionary<T> where T : Animal
{
    private IDictionary<int,T> animalDictionary = new Dictionary<int,T>();
    
    public void AddAnimal(T animal)
    {
        animalDictionary.Add(animal);
    }
}
```

and here is the calling side code :

```
public static void Main()
{
    AnimalDictionary<Cat> animalDictionary = new AnimalDictionary<Cat>();
    animalDictionary.AddAnimal(new Cat());
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: I fear this won't work, because I need a still place to implement unique methods in GiraffeDictionary and TigerDictionary. For example: TigerDictionary has methods to expose the subset of Tigers that are hunting, while GiraffeDictionary has methods to expose the subset of Giraffes that are members of a specific herd. An AnimalDictionary<Giraffe/Tiger> can't implement those methods.

Comment: @Quasar You can implement those animal-specific methods with [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). You just can't add animal-specific *fields*.

Comment: @Quasar You can still inherit from `AnimalDictionary<T>` for specific animals like `TigerDictionary: AnimalDictionary<Tiger>`

Comment: @Orifjon This looks like it might be exactly what I was missing.